# How to know if my Python Program is supported for all Python versions ? pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pip

I would like to make a program that has some dependencies and modules work across all python 3 versions (i.e. from 3.5 to 3.9 etc..) How to achieve this? What do I need ?
(will be installed through pip)

Comment: If it works in 3.5 then it should work in 3.5+ so test in the lowest release version that you have to support. Features tend to be added rather than removed

Comment: So if I test it on lowest version and it works, It MUST work on later versions? And then when lower python version is installed on target machine it will work normally ? won't say need update on pip install or something ?